# Dynamics 2011 Marketing List Workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, microsoft-dynamics

Hey hopefully someone here can help.

I want to be able to create a workflow in Dynamics 2011 that operates something like this :

If a contact gets added to a static marketing list, then update a field on that contact.

I can't find how to do this and am guessing it might need some custom coding rather than using the workflow builder within dynamics.

Any help would be great and please ask if you need any more information.

Thanks

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: nothing yet, i just want to know if it is possible first. Is there a method to get the members of the marketing list and then update fields, the reason for this is i need to sync members of a static list to a dynamic one. (Don't ask why it's a workaround for something)